# using _getch() in <conio.h>, significance on "_"

Tags: c++

so I am teachuing myself c++ and I came accross conio.h

and I usually had a problem with cin.get(), and sometimes I had to duplicate it to keep the cosole open...

**code:**

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hi" ;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

what is the significance behind the "_" part of "_getch()"?

Comment: For a long and technical answer, [see this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate. The OP is asking why the CRT function have a different name (with underscore)

Answer (score 0):

For a long and technical answer, see this one. –  Joachim Pileborg

https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, Microsoft decided to move to the ISO C++ standard in VS2005.
They deprecated the POSIX names (e.g. `getch`) in favor of the ISO names (`_getch`).

You can use the POSIX names in VS by declaring this before the first header include:

```
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
```